# How to run the same fragment several times?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm creating an app that will allow the user to **take little tests**. There is therefore a `TestActivity` made up by a `PreTestFragment` (with a button "Start Test"), a `TestFragment` and a `PostTestFragment` (with results of the test). As `TestFragment` will be the fragment hosting a single question I want it to be **displayed several times** (let's say 10).

All I could come up with was making a `static` counter that is incremented every time the user presses NEXT in a `TestFragment` and that makes him quit after the counter reached 10.

I'm new to fragment management, so I feel like I may have done several errors in the implementation of the `onClick()` of the NEXT button.

```
static private int current_question;


public void onClick(View view) {
    FragmentManager mng = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fgmTr = mng.beginTransaction();
    Fragment currentFgm = mng.findFragmentByTag(FragmentTags.TEST_FTAG.toString());
    Fragment nextFgm;
    Bundle bundle = currentFgm.getArguments();
    if (current_question < 10) { // test still running
        current_question++;
        nextFgm = mng.findFragmentByTag(FragmentTags.TEST_FTAG.toString());
        // ...
        // putting needed data in the bundle
        // ...
        if (nextFgm == null)
            nextFgm = new TestFragment();
    } else { // test is finished
        nextFgm = mng.findFragmentByTag(FragmentTags.POST_FTAG.toString());
        // ...
        // putting different needed data in the bundle
        // ...
        if (nextFgm == null)
            nextFgm = new PostTestFragment();
    }
    nextFgm.setArguments(bundle);
    fgmTr.replace(R.id.test_body, nextFgm, FragmentTags.POST_FTAG.toString());     
    fgmTr.addToBackStack(null);
    fgmTr.commit();
}


@Override
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    super.setArguments(args);
    // Should I use if-else here too to pass different data in the bundle?
}
```

Running it and pressing "NEXT" the first time I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active

How to fix this code?

Comment: What is wrong with this code? What does it not do that you expect it to do?

Comment: @Bryan thanks! Check the edited message please

Comment: You can rethink this design by using swipe views!

Answer (score 0):

If your fragment (nextFgm) has already been created, you can't call setArguments.
take a look:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29

Answer (score 0):

Usually i did it by create a new fragment's instance every time:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new myFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```